# Python: IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory (Raspberry PI)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

i am trying to write a program which will output a text file; it will rename while i execute it.

however i cant execute it. With the error message `[IOError: Errno 2 No such file or directory]`

here is my code:

```
from Adafruit_BMP085 import BMP085
from time import sleep
import time
import datetime
import pickle, sys, os

while True:     

class data():
    def __init__(self):
        self.tp = tps()
        self.savedata()

    def savedata(self):             
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        timestamp = now.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
        filename= 'Temperature_'+ timestamp +'.txt'

        f=open (filename,'a')

        timestamp = now.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")

        self.tp.updateTempAndPressure()

        outvalue  = self.tp.temp 
        outvalue_1= self.tp.altitude
        outvalue_2= self.tp.pressure/100            

        outstring = str(timestamp)+" Temperature:"+str(outvalue)+ " C Altitude: "+str(outvalue_1)+ "m Pressure: " +str(outvalue_2)+ "hPa" + "\n"

        print outstring
        f.write(outstring)
        f.close()

data()  
time.sleep(1)
```

it there any function that i miss it?Is there anything else wrong with my code that would cause me could not run the entire task?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following statement create a string like `'2013/12/15 20:44:59`

```
timestamp = now.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
```

`/` is path name separator in unix. To make a file you need intermediate directories.

```
>>> open('1/2/3', 'a')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '1/2/3'
>>> open('1-2-3', 'a')
<open file '1-2-3', mode 'a' at 0xb74bd128>
```

How about change `/` to other character like `-`?

```
timestamp = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```